# Switching problems in class D amplifier

Tags: pcb, amplifier, pcb-design, switching, class-d

I'm building a class D amplifier with a dsPIC as PWM modulator.

The part of the schematic that I want to talk about is the interaction between the microcontroller output (pwm signal) and the gate of the MOSFET. I use TC4420 and TC4429 as gate drivers.

I know that there could be some overshooting (I think it's called "ringing") every time the output of the driver switches (for the resonant circuit created from gate capacitance and parasitic inductance), but I can see a lot of overshooting even between the output of the microcontroller and the input of the driver that has high impedance!!! 
Is it normal or am I missing something?? If it's normal, is it true that that overshooting can be lowered only with a series resistor?

Here is the waveform between dsPIC and driver:
[image]

And this is the output of the gate driver:
[image]

Talking about switching in the same pcb of a class D amp, is it true that is recomended to have two separate grounds for logic signals and for power? I searched the internet but I don't get this point: how can i have two separate grounds if the power cables has only one ground wire?

Comment: output of gate driver looks normal

Comment: Yes, you could drop a resistor between the PIC and the gate driver, but it is probably not necessary. Some processors also have a gate drive or slew rate setting that you can turn down. Alternatively, make the trace between the PIC and the driver wider and shorter (lower inductance). But all this, again, seems unnecessary.

Comment: First question : what is your measurement setup? There is no point trying to fix ringing in your circuit if it's actually caused by your scope probe ground lead.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for the advices. I also have another problem related to switches: I see a lot of noise in the power supply at the same frequency of the pwm signal. Inserting a lot of bypass capacitors is the only way to reduce this noise?

Comment: You should address @BrianDrummond 's question and make sure that is real noise. Generally, though, yeah, you'd reduce the voltage ripple with more capacitance.